# How to get column value in selectedItems wpf?

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I have many records from a database and i display it in a ListView. I need to delete it if I select it (multi-selection).

But i need the Id (a column) to delete it and i can't get it. Please help^^

exemple:

column: id  name  note  ...
        1   name1 note1 
        2 ...
        3 ...

if i select 1 and 3 I need to get the value (1 and 3).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

loop through all the seleted rows and try this.

Subitems[*columnnumber*] will be the column numbr of the id field

lv.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text